# How to convert from BYTE* to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, qstring

I have a [DATA_BLOB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381414(v=VS.85).aspx) structure but I need to convert it to QString. How can I do this?

Comment: why do you want to convert it to a `QString`?

Comment: @Idan K: for the compatibility with other code

Comment: but does it actually contain text? if so, in what encoding?

Comment: @Idan K: I use (BYTE*)qstring.toUtf8().constData() to put data into DATA_BLOB. I suppose I must use QString::fromUtf8((const char*)datablob.pbData) to get data...

Comment: actually that looks like a bug. `toUtf8` returns a `QByteArray` by value, you're taking it's internal pointer using `constData` but that pointer probably gets freed right after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QString` [constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#QString-8) with a [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qbytearray.html) parameter.
You can use too the [constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#QString-7) with the `const char*` parameter too

Hope that helps

Comment: Is it possible to convert BYTE* to QString without explicit conversion to const char*?

Comment: I do not know any way to convert from BYTE* to QString without excplictly cast to const char*

Answer (score 0):

```
BYTE* myByteBlob; 
int myByteBlobSize;

// Get the blob, find out the size.
// ...

QString myString( QByteArray( myByteBlob, myByteBlobSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   BYTE* pu8_RawData = (BYTE*)i_RawData.parray->pvData;
   DWORD u32_RawLen  =        i_RawData.parray->rgsabound[0].cElements;

   qDebug() << QString(QByteArray((const char*) pu8_RawData, (int)u32_RawLen));
```